# Free 2D Array Of Char Pointers, free(): Invalid Pointers Error

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation, free

My program runs without error but when I want to free 2D char array (like arguments[0]) it gives me : **free(): invalid pointer, fish: Job 1, './a.out' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)**

```c
/**
 * @brief Parses the input into arguments
 *
 * EXP:
 * "head -n 5 foo.txt"
 * arguments[0] = "head"
 * arguments[1] = "-n"
 * arguments[2] = "5"
 * arguments[3] = "foo.txt"
 * arguments[4] = NULL
 *
 * @param input
 * @return char**
 */
char** getArguments(char* input, int numOfArgs) {
    char copy_arguments[BUFSIZ]; /* To parse input */
    strcpy(copy_arguments, input);

    char** arguments = calloc(numOfArgs + 1, sizeof(char*));
    if (arguments == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    /*allocate memory for arguments depending their length*/
    char* argument = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfArgs; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            argument = strtok(copy_arguments, " ");
        } else {
            argument = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }

        int size_of_arg = strlen(argument);
        arguments[i] = calloc((size_of_arg + 1), sizeof(char));
        strcpy(arguments[i], argument);
    }
    arguments[numOfArgs + 1] = NULL;

    return arguments;
}

int main() {
    char **output = getArguments("hello world -n vim", 4);
    free(output[0]);
}
```

Comment: Could you please include the code where you use `free`?

Comment: `int size_of_arg = strlen(argument);` You need to be aware that `numOfArgs` might not match the number of tokens you get via `strtok`. In that case `strtok` will return `NULL` and when you pass that `argument` pointer around you cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: Any reason why you don't free `output[1]`.. `output[3]` and `output`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function invokes undefined behavior. There are allocated `numOfArgs + 1` pointers

```
char** arguments = calloc(numOfArgs + 1, sizeof(char*));
```

So the valid range of indices is `[0, numOfArgs]`.

Thus in this statement

```
arguments[numOfArgs + 1] = NULL;
```

there is an access to memory outside the allocated array.

Instead you have to write

```
arguments[numOfArgs] = NULL;
```

In general you should check that the returned pointer is not equal to `NULL` as for example

```
if ( output ) free(output[0]);
```

Comment: It fixed my problem. I didn't check boundaries.

Comment: @SigmundFreud If the problem  is resolved then close the question selecting the best answer and your reputation will be increased.:)